# In which comic did the Phoenix Force destroyed a planet protected by Herald of Galactus?

Tags: story-identification, marvel, phoenix-force

I once read a comic in which ruler of the planet was warned about the Phoenix Force. But, he told that he was a *Herald of Galactus* and he wasn't scared of anyone. He looked like Thanos, but with a big hammer in hand.

In the same comic, the Phoenix Force destroyed his planet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### This is from the [Marvel Point One](http://marvel.wikia.com/Point_One_Vol_1_1) (2012), collection of stories which includes the story 'Nova Harbinger', drawn by Ed McGuiness and written by Jeph Loeb. In it, [Nova](http://marvel.wikia.com/Samuel_Alexander_(Earth-616)) (Sam Alexander, not Richard Rider) attempts to warn Terrax (former Herald of Galactus) and the planet he protects that the White Phoenix Force will destroy the planet unless they evacuate.

[image]